How to disable the warning message for g4f version deprecation?
I am using this code to get my response out of the model :
from g4f.client import Client

client = Client()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello"}],
)

This code is run through subprocess.Popen() call like so:
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Python38\\python.exe','-Wignore', 'C:\\Users\\user\\proj\\projName\\chatgpt.py'],
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, env=env)

But the call to client.chat.completions.create() generates this warning message before actually returning the model response:
New g4f version: 0.3.2.4 (current: 0.3.2.2) | pip install -U g4f

My question is how to suppress that warning message from being generated by the mentioned call?

You can suppress it using the warnings module:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Or, you can resolve the issue by upgrading the g4f package to the latest version via pip install -U g4f

You can also use sys.stdout to redirect standard output temporarily.
For example:
# Save the current stdout
old_stdout = sys.stdout

# Redirect all output that would normally go to stdout (e.g., the console) into a buffer instead
sys.stdout = io.StringIO()

# Call the g4f function that generates the warning here
...
...

# Restore stdout to its original state
sys.stdout = old_stdout


I even tried warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) but the warning still outputs, I also don't want to upgrade the current version of g4f

I have tried the warnings command and it worked well in my environment.

what if the code mentioned is within another module which called through subprocess.Popen()? will that still work?

I am not sure about that. Have you tried to redirect standard output temporarily using sys.stdout. For example, putting old_stdout = sys.stdout  and sys.stdout = io.StringIO() before client.chat.completions.create() and restoring the stdout by
sys.stdout = old_stdout after.

why there's a need to do sys.stdout = io.StringIO() ?

It is used to redirect all output that would normally go to stdout (e.g., the console) into a buffer instead. I have updated my answer.
